# Where are the Razor assemblies?

Tags: webmatrix, razor

I'm playing around with WebMatrix and I'd just like to explore some of the razor stuff behind the scenes... but my Reflector skills (and my brain) are failing me.  Does anyone know offhand what assembly I should start looking in (and/or a location for it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the assemblies are installed into Program Files as well as into the GAC. The local folder is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies
```